# SQL Server - Fails to import Data-Tier Application from SQL Azure

Tags: sql-server, azure, data-tier-applications, bacpac

I'm attempting to import a database to my local SQL Server 2012 instance from SQL Azure using the "Import Data-Tier Application" wizard.

I simply exported the database to blob storage, then downloaded the file and then selected to import the database.

This fails each time with the error message below:

[image]

The error is occurring because it seems to want to create a DEFAULT constraint twice. Has anyone else had this issue?

Comment: I have similar error but for SQL Server 2014. But I can import the same database from 4 days old export.
I don't know solution unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error and solved it by installing the preview version of SQL 2016 SQL Management Studio.